# Recent badges are broken on facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, facebook.stackoverflow

The subview of Stack Overflow for Facebook should show badges scoped to the tags within the view, not all tags.

The badges shown are for all of Stack Overflow not just only http://facebook.stackoverflow.com

[image: Recent Badges as of timestamp of edit]

Comment: Whadayamean? http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags shows just facebook badges.

Comment: [Recent Badges](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3rkup.png)

Comment: Right, forgot that list existed. So, "The `recent badges` list on the frontpage right-hand column should only show badges awarded for facebook-tagged questions" would be clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't possible to separate, for example Electorate in the example above is for voting...it's awarded for all content on the master site, voting across all questions.  Filtering of "if it was awarded for facebook stuff" is incredibly difficult...if even possible in many cases.  It's a very significant complication of the badge code (that's already complicated), so I'd say this is an issue not worth fixing.

For this to work, each badge would need to be reviewed and (probably) changed.  Also, keep in mind questions can appear or disappear from the sub-site if a question has tags added or removed - so for the list to be accurate even in this hypothetical scenario it would need to be continually re-checked or have another mapping system in place (still bearing in mind many badges do not map to a single post, so the existing tag engine system can't work).

I wouldn't classify this as a bug, these badges *are* awarded on that site.  Since the badges are shared (there's only one list) with the main site, these badges *are* the most recently awarded to users listed there.

Comment: If it's not a bug what would you call it? Honestly, if this is the answer then I don't see the point in the sub-site or rather that display, because it's not indicative to the subsite and there is no notice saying such other than what you have just said

Comment: @phwd - the sub-site has never been *completely* segregated, we made the decision early on that badges would not be separate between a sub-site and its master...it's insanely complicated to even think about.  You can think of it a bug if you want, but it's working the way it's intended to...because the alternative is borderline crazy to maintain and nearly impossible to optimize.  The payout for the effort here is very, *very* low, so it's not something we'll be undertaking.

Comment: Okay, it's just that this is going to occur for other http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136976/wrong-number-of-suggested-edits-on-facebook-so http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141636/weekly-monthly-quarterly-reputation-leagues-link-broken-on-facebook-stackove stuff as well. I'm guessing the same logic applies there as well, oh well

Comment: @phwd - some of these things we can do...it's badges in particular that are crazy, especially on large data sets such as SO.  I'll take a look at the other bugs once we finish planning the SQL migrations for (hopefully) this weekend.