# weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues link broken on facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues, facebook.stackoverflow

The link for the league, https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/facebook-stackoverflow points to a "Page Not Found" instead of either Stack Overflow league (which is still not the expected result) or Facebook Stack Overflow league (not sure if it has ever been implemented).

Comment: Dont worry, **Panda** is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not the leagues you're looking for...

Seriously, we shouldn't have shown that link (just as we don't show the top % links in each profile) because the leagues don't make much sense.  Given that reputation is not separate inside a subsite (it's the same reputation as on stackoverflow.com), we'd be effectively showing a league of "users with 200+ rep that asked or answered a facebook question"...but with reputation from *everywhere* on stackoverflow.com (not a value constrained to activity in facebook.stackoverflow.com).

The link will no longer appear on any subsites after the next build.